# Flowtype extend object type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

As JavaScript developer I'm new to type checking and I struggle to understand why this simple code is not working:

```js
type Animal = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  type: 'dog' | 'cat'
};

type Dog = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  type: 'dog',
  color: string
};

function printAnimal(animal: Animal): string {
  return `${animal.type}: ${animal.name}`;
}

const buddy: Dog = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Buddy',
  type: 'dog',
  color: 'black'
}

printAnimal(buddy);
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to have a method that accepts interface. This however gives me error: `Cannot call 'printAnimal' with 'buddy' bound to 'animal' because string literal 'dog' [1] is incompatible with string literal 'cat' [2] in property 'type'.`.

What I tried:

1. `interface Animal { // ...}` - does not work.
2. Remove typing from `buddy` - it work's but I'm not satisfied. Sometimes I do want to have more strict type (so I know I'm dealing with dog not cat) but still use general method that accept any animal.
3. I tried changing `type: 'dog' | 'cat'` to `type: string` - does not work. I would expect `'dog'` string is subtype of general `string` type but it's not. On the other hand even if it works it wouldn't be enough - sometimes I know that my app accepts only dogs and cats not any other animals.

Thanks for reading and I hope I can get some help from you guys! Here's live version: [Try Flow - live example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCAdgJYC2AhjGALxgDeqYYpAJgFxjECu5ARngBOAGmbdK5PFwDOGIaWIBzMS2z4uAcjZwlmsAB8wmgMaUMm1AF8A3OnUEAIrrqNx7LrwHDVEqbPlFFXEHLR09XxM4eCEAhWVrO1QoHmITDFI4YjAceIwSCmoACkoyKhguAvKASjigtxYhPAweIWyAAwASBlLCmAA6Bysubt7y-uJJPCt2uyt0KOI5MH4eNjYsLmclVyYASA8wAEZfPcn-YwAhNY3NU9DjcLvxFiiYrX4YShMAa0t51C5RT5MrFVbrLDVGxAA)

Comment: I've been able to find solution by actually specifing two explicit type definitions: for `cat` and `dog` and then create a type out of those two with disjoint union. Here's [live version](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoMqAuBPADgUzAGEBDTMAXjAG90wBLAEwC4wA7AVwFsAjfAJwA0dNiS75WAZ0z96bAObCwYHAVYByAMZl1qAL4BuVFjyEAInHmUadJq068BS9mIlhpshc9Vv1jS+rOmnDw-FIycvL6RiYEYACCbPRcJDDWpOQAPmAW8jFQHGyamPRwbGC4npiJyakAFCRJKTCsNc0AlOGeVrTK-PiYHPzlAAYAJNSNtTAAdD56rBNTzTOi4nojRnrGwWzSYDwcjIzYrLnWtACQdmAAjM6Xa74AQkcngXSXPhr+8h-KymCoQ0PBgJE0AGtdNtUJU5NUmvVDsdsO0DEA). Still looking for better ways!

Comment: after playing around a bit, I found this cyclic weirdness to be working: [live](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCAdgJYC2AhjGALxgAUAwpRmAD5gAicA5gJRgAZGADeqMGFIATAFxhiAV3IAjPACcANBIWVyeeQGcM60sV7bJ2fPMrEsqAL4BudNYIs29EhWrCxOu7yAOQAxqzBTq6YuAQ8vHREZFQ0IuJWsSHSfMGWYKFw8OpGJma8UeioUIrEoRikcMRgOKbEGD4pDHa+MPId1PwlrQnpYOp4GIrqTQAGACSi3SkAdO6O8gtL1MvEeniOjJvJ2wVFjvwzro7oBcTGYCqK0tJY8vGJ4gCQMvIAjHmfXb6EIAISeL1yOk+QTAwWyvEhkkkpzgxVhKhglFCAGtItdUC0zO1jjAGI9nlh+M4gA). Well kind of, because imo. this `animal.color` should throw, as `Cat` doesn't implement a `color`

Comment: Thanks for your input @Thomas ! It's definitely nice that your solution is not throwing error however I don't like cyclomatic complexity - it looks like `Animal` now needs `Cat` type to be defined and `Cat` type need `Animal` type to be defined. So for now I'm rolling with `type Animal = Cat | Dog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the `Animal` type an **interface** since it's describing your types implementations as a "parent". And it would make sense if you enforce it by extending your `Dog` type via a **union** since that's the point of using typings to reach a stronger type-checking.

This can be written like this:

```js
/* @flow */

interface Animal {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  type: 'dog' | 'cat'
};

type Dog = Animal & {
  type: 'dog',
  color: string
};

function printAnimal(animal: Animal): string {
  return `${animal.type}: ${animal.name}`;
}

const buddy: Dog = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Buddy',
  type: 'dog',
  color: 'black'
}

printAnimal(buddy);
```